# Guppies and turtles together?

Tags: turtles, pest-control, guppies

Since turtles have eaten all of my goldfish, I stopped putting more fish in their aquarium.

Now the problem is: today morning I saw too many mosquito larvae on surface of water. Seems like turtles don't like eating them, but I know guppies do. But I am concerned whether I can put them in one tank with turtles?

Is there any solution I can apply to prevent aquarium water from being infested by mosquito larvae?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try guppies but chances are your turtles will eat them, however if you add enough plants for them to hide in they may survive. Another easy way is to just scoop out the larvae with a small fish net.

Mosquitoes like to lay their eggs on still water so having something to keep the flow going would help, I assume for your turtles you have a canister filter? The output on it can be placed near the surface to have that ripple effect on the water.

Comment: `"Another easy way is to just scoop them with a net."` I didn't get you. Do you mean create a partition with net between turtle and fish?

Comment: sorry I will clarify, you can buy a small fish net (what people use to scoop fish) and scoop out the larvae as you seen them. With the pump making the water flow they shouldn't come back, if they do they might be something other than mosquito larvae.

Answer (score 1):

Turtles eat fish. They do not have any specific fish they don't eat. Even if the fish is too big the turtle will slowly eat the fish a little bit at a time, for example by biting fins, eyes, etc. You may have to just scoop the larvae  often and keep tank light off if possible.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of guppies swim in the aquarium of my turtle (yellow bellied slider). The turtle is assumed to be 10 years old and does not catch them actively.

Young turtles of this kind hunt and eat fish, but older ones eat primarily plants. But they do not spurn dead fish, especially if these dead fish are fresh, so we haven't had any fish corpses lying around.

One rule we have learned: the fish should have no long flippy-flappy tail fin. Those beautiful ones, with long tail fins resembling bridal veils, swim too slow, so the turtle may eat them accidentally if the food gets them both lured to come close to each other.